# as3 array error #1009 null object reference

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I am learning arrays on as3 and I managed (with help from users on this website) to get my array working, but now I get a #1009 error, the error occurs when the `box_MC` hits `finish_MC` and changes to the next scene, from what I understand its happening because the array still running? not 100% sure.

> Error:   TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of
>   a null object reference.at
>   arraystut3_fla::MainTimeline/onEnterThisFrame()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have simply forgot to remove the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener attached to your `stage` object which is still fired every frame, and because all elements ( objects ) used in your `onEnterThisFrame` function are only in your first scene ( `Scene 1` ), you will still get that error.

To avoid that, you have to remove that listener like this :

```
if(box_MC.hitTestObject(finish_MC)) {

    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterThisFrame); 

    trace ("ending");
    gotoAndPlay (1, "tester");

} else {
    trace ("not yet");
}
```

Or you can remove it in the 1st frame of your 2nd scene ( `tester` ) :

```
stop();
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterThisFrame);
```

Hope that can help.